# How to compute frequency response from impulse response?

Tags: response, frequency

I got the task to compute a frequency response from a given impulse response @ n equidistant pulsatance frequencies omega within the interval [0,pi] but I don't know how to to this.

So I thought the frequency response is:

```
# G(z) = Sum mue=[0:M] of (b_mue*z^-mue) / Sum v=[0:N] of (a_v*z^-v)
# G(z) = B(z^-1) / A(z^-1)
```

But how do I get these values from only a impulse response g?
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the z-transformed of g to get G(z) ? That should give you the frequency response.